# jqGrid resizeStop listen globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am currently trying to figure out how to deal with saving the size of columnheads in jqGrid, but first of all i cant seem to find a way to globally listen to all jqGrid resizeStops.

So i am trying to make sure i get the element and size of the columnheader when resizeStop is called.
I want to do this on all jqGrids.

Is it even a possibility?

I already tried calling the resizeStop individually but it doesn't really seem to be efficient.

I did this by binding to jqGridResizeStart on an element by Gridelement.grid.jqGrid
But i want to do this globally

Comment: Which is the version of jqGrid used?

Comment: What is your definition for global event in jqGrid? The event can be "global" and can't be not - it depend on the realization.

Comment: Global is that i can listen to the jqGrid even at all times.

Comment: Using lastest version of jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

All the grid events are per grid instance. You can easy make this globally if you just use resizeStop as parameter function without to use bind. This can be something like this.

```
function My_Global_Listen_Resize (new_width, index) {
/// here you code to listen
     // this - point to the current grid instance
}
```

Then in all grids you can just add it like this:

```
$("#grid1"). jqGrid({
...
resizeStop : My_Global_Listen_Resize ,
...
});

$("#grid2"). jqGrid({
...
resizeStop : My_Global_Listen_Resize ,
...
});
```